# Node tries to send headers but previous response seems still opened

Tags: node.js

I have the following code:

```
app.get('/pull-requests', function (request) {
  fetchRepos(fetchPullRequests);
  app.on('pull-requests:fetched', function (pullRequestsByRepo) {
    var html = "";

    _.each(pullRequestsByRepo, function (pullRequests) {
      html += 'There is <strong>'+ pullRequests.length +'</strong> pending pull request(s) for <strong>'+ pullRequests[0].title +'</strong>:';
      html += '<ul>';
      _.each(pullRequests, function (pullRequest) {
        html += '<li><em>'+ pullRequest.title +'</em> (<a href="'+ pullRequest.url +'">'+ pullRequest.url +'</a>)</li>';
      });
      html += '</ul>';
    });

    response.send(html);
  });
});
```

It works fine once. Every second request ends raising an error `Can't set headers after they are sent.`.

---

EDIT: More code to explicit the logic

```
function fetchRepos (callback) {
  _options.path = '/orgs/'+ app.get('org') +'/repos?client_id='+ app.get('client_id') +'&client_secret='+ app.get('client_secret');

  // Fetch the list of repos for a given organisation
  var request = https.get(_options, function (res) {
    data = "";

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function () {
      var repos = JSON.parse(data);
      return callback(repos);
    });
  });

  request.on('error', function (error) {
    console.log('Problem with request: '+ e);
  });
}

function fetchPullRequests (repos) {
  var pullRequests = [];
  _.each(repos, function (repo, index) {
    _options.path = '/repos/'+ app.get('org') +'/'+ repo.name +'/pulls?client_id='+ app.get('client_id') +'&client_secret='+ app.get('client_secret');
    var request = https.get(_options, function (res) {
      (function () {
        var data = "";

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          data += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
          data = JSON.parse(data);
          if (data.length > 0) {
            pullRequests.push(data);
          }

          if (index == (repos.length - 1)) {
            app.emit('pull-requests:fetched', pullRequests);
          }
        });
      })();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: What does `fetchRepos()` do with `response` object?

Comment: @palanik, it does actually nothing. I removed this argument from my functions definitions but forgot to remove it in this specific line. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that whenever you call `app.on('pull-requests:fetched', …)`, you add a new listener, meaning that when the second request arrives, it will trigger the first one again.

node then complains because you try reply twice to the first request.

You could fix your immediate issue by calling `app.once`, which would ensure that the only fires once, but you would still have an issue if 2 requests arrive at the same time.

The correct pattern in this case is to pass a callback to fetchRepos.

Comment: I actually prevent such case. I updated my question with almost all missing code (it's basic application) so you can see how I handle it. And to be more explicit regarding the issue I'm facing, when I tell it works fine once, I mean I see the result and I have no errors. And the second time, the server literally crashes and I see no result at all.

Comment: when do you do `app.emit` for the 2nd time, you notify both the listener of the second request AND the one of the first. This happens because you never unregister the listener. You can check that by calling `console.log(app.listeners('pull-requests:fetched').length);` right before you call `app.emit`.

Comment: I get your point. I'm new with NodeJS and I still have a few problem regarding a few things. Thanks for your help :)